# Hudson SCP file upload fails because I used ANT to rename the war file

Tags: hudson, file-transfer, scp

I am using Hudson 2.1.2 using SCP 1.8 and Maven 3.0.4.  I have the server setup in manager page, and it connects and uploads the war file ok as long as I didn't rename it.

As soon as I put the  in the pom.xml file

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>run-ant-rename-war</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <tasks>
                        <move
                            file="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.war"
                            tofile="${project.build.directory}/my-project.war" />
                    </tasks>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

hudson completes the package and renames the file.  It then connects to my server but fails on upload with following message.

> ERROR: Failed to upload files 3: Permission denied at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2289) at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._put(ChannelSftp.java:485) at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:439) at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:406) at be.certipost.hudson.plugin.SCPSite.upload(SCPSite.java:239) at be.certipost.hudson.plugin.SCPRepositoryPublisher.perform(SCPRepositoryPublisher.java:211) at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:36) at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:630) at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:608) at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$RunnerImpl.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:789) at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:553) at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1391) at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:414) at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88) at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:145)
>   [DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update; build not configured with trigger: kc_project_usc #52

If i use an FTP program like FileZilla it will upload that exact same file with no problems.  Any ideas why that is?